# C++ concept example from "Simplifying the use of concepts"

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I was reading Bjarne Stroustrup's mini-paper ["Simplifying the use of concepts"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2906.pdf) and I came across the following snippet (page 9), which I reproduce below:

> ```
> concept ABx<typename T> {
>    void a(T&);
>    void b(T&);
> };
> concept Ax<typename T> {
>    void a(T&);
> };
> ```
>
> Obviously, every type that’s an `ABx` is also an `Ax`, so:
>
> ```
> template<Ax T> void f(T);
> template<ABx T> void f(T t);
> void h(X x) // X is a type for which a(x) is valid
> {
>     f(x); // ambiguous
> }
> ```
>
> In other words, in general, we have to protect against `ACx`’s [sic] `a()` being different from `Ax`’s `a()`. If these two `a()`s can be different we cannot accept the call `g(t)` above because it would call “the wrong `a()`.”

I am having difficulty understanding this example; in particular, I don't understand the discussion at the end.

1. Did Bjarne mean `ABx` rather than `ACx`? (Where I marked [sic])
2. Did Bjarne mean that `X` is a type for which `a(x)` and `b(x)` are valid? If only `a(x)` is valid, then I do not think `template<ABx T> void f(T t);` should apply, so there is no ambiguity.
3. I don't know what Bjarne means when he claims that the two `a()` implementations could be different. Don't they have to be the same?

I'm sure Bjarne's example is right, and I just don't know enough about C++ concepts. I would love if someone could enlighten me.

Comment: Are you sure that 2009 paper is still current with N4040?

Comment: Absolutely not! But I am still interested in this paper as a snapshot of the design issues the concepts committee was working through before they decided to axe concepts from the next standard.